# Проблема с Viewpager в CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

Имеется вот такой `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Фрагмент(убрал только OnClickListener кнопок, которые находятся в TabLayout):

```
public class FragmentFirst extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        //Viewpager для каждой вкладки
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        // Назначение вкладок в TabLayout
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.result_tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_name);


        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        return view;
    }

    // Добавление фрагментов в TabLayout
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("genres", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(), "");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentA(), resources.getString(R.string.tabA));
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentB(), resources.getString(R.string.tabB));
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentC(), resources.getString(R.string.tabC));

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(9);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    }


    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `viewpager` изначально не откликается. Чтобы "активировать" viewpager, нужно нажать один раз на него, либо свайпнуть вверх `CoordinatorLayout`.

Как это предотвратить?

Comment: А зачем `Coordinator` в `Relative` обернут?

Comment: Делал по тюториалу, который не могу найти. Убрал `RelativeLayout`, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Про `Relative` просто поинтересовался. Нужно наверное код добавить потому, что здесь вроде бы все в порядке.

Comment: Попробуй задать android:layout_height="match_parent" для ViewPager

Comment: @Colibri Добавил код фрагмента, если он необходим.

Comment: @VitalyTomashevsky изменил `layout_height` на `match_parent`, проблема осталась.

Comment: @Rauf Aliyev
Что то я не пойму, макет который вы скинули получается `fragment_a`, вы его раздуваете в `FragmentFirst`, в адаптере вы добавляете `FragmentA` он другой макет использует же?